# How to display multiple Images from from multiple urls in a single Tkinter canvas using Python

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, web-scraping, tkinter-canvas

I have a list of url's and each url contains only one image, and I want to display all the images on a single tkinter canvas using python also the list contain some url which does not contain image tkinter should ignores those url.

I created a code which displays only one image at a time.

```
import io
import base64
try:
    # Python2
    import Tkinter as tk
    from urllib2 import urlopen
except ImportError:
    # Python3
    import tkinter as tk
    from urllib.request import urlopen
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("display a website image")

w = 800
h = 600
x = 200
y = 300

root.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (w, h, x, y))


image_url = "http://www.okclipart.com/img2/yrdulrdklckodbfcqsuy.png"
image_byt = urlopen(image_url).read()
image_b64 = base64.encodestring(image_byt)
photo = tk.PhotoImage(data=image_b64)

cv = tk.Canvas(bg='white')
cv.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand='yes')
cv.create_image(10, 10, image=photo, anchor='nw')
root.mainloop()
```

sample list of images url

```
urllist =['https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d0/NoCopyright.png/600px-NoCopyright.png','http://www.okclipart.com/img16/kjlhjznjvkokwqpalupl.png'
,'http://www.okclipart.com/img16/qcmwejvtwuufltxsibbn.png',
'http://www.okclipart.com/img2/yrdulrdklckodbfcqsuy.png']
```

Also there are some url in the list which does not contain any images so it shoud ignore those urls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **ignoring invalid urls**: `try ... except urllib2.HTTPError` will help you with this
2. **loading several images**: Iterate through your `urllist` and load each of those images. When successfull, draw it onto you canvas.

```py
#from urllib.request import HTTPError #py3
#from urllib2 import HTTPError #py2
#... 
def load_image_to_base64(image_url):
    """ Load an image from a web url and return its data base64 encoded"""
    image_byt = urlopen(image_url).read()
    image_b64 = base64.encodestring(image_byt)
    return image_b64

# load photos to photos list
urllist = ['http://www.okclipart.com/img16/kjlhjznjvkokwqpalupl.png', 
           'invalidurltest', 
           'http://www.okclipart.com/YouWontFindThisImage.png']
photos = []
for i, url in enumerate(urllist):
    print(i,"loading",url)
    try:
        photo = tk.PhotoImage(data=load_image_to_base64(url))
        photos.append(photo)
        print("done")
    except HTTPError as err:
        print("image not found, http error code:", err.code)
    except ValueError:
        print("invalid url", url)

# iterate through photos and put them onto the canvas
for photo in photos:
    cv.create_image(10*i, 10*i, image=photo, anchor='nw')

root.mainloop()
#...
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I was also wondering how to add scrolling features to it as the images are to large and its not possible to see all the images at once.

Comment: @MukeshJha So did it help?
**About scrolling:** As always: What have you tried? It's also not part of your question. [1st answer on google.](http://www.swharden.com/wp/2010-03-03-viewing-large-images-with-scrollbars-using-python-tk-and-pil/)
You could also resize those the images, so that all of them fit on one screen side by side.

Comment: Thanks sir, your code is working fine it helped me alot.